# C++ Creating a Queue of Structs with Struct definition in a header file

Tags: c++, struct, queue, header-files

I have the definition of a struct with a constructor in a C++ header file called my_header.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

struct r {

    bool b;
    int i;
    int j;

    r(int num1, int num2)
    {
    // do stuff
    }

}
```

I've included the header file in main, and also included queue, and I am attempting to do this in my main file:

```
#include "my_header.h"
#include <queue>

int main (void)
{
queue<r> ROB;

ROB.push(r(0xFFFF,1));

return 0;
}
```

Eclipse is giving me an error on the line of code where I'm pushing, saying:

"Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void push(const r &)
void push(r &&)
'"

I went into my project properties and ensured that the header file is seen. I'm not getting an error when I declare my queue. Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: I made some edits, please let me know if they're sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, the only errors you should be getting is a missing semicolon after your struct definition and queue not being declared in your scope.

Here's the example with those errors fixed compiling:
http://cpp.sh/9aoay

Comment: I don't get an error with the struct definition inside of the main .cpp file. It's when I move it to the header file that the error arises. I can't figure out why this is.